# How to use different CSS in the same page

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

How can I use different CSS in the same page?

For example I have two primefaces header in the same page and I want to apply different CSS for them.

Is there a way to do this? When I try to add below lines inside head tags, just one of them is working.

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="myheader1.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="myheader2.css" />
```

*CSS files*:

```
.ui-layout-unit-header{
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: buttonface !important;
}

.ui-layout-unit-header{
    font-size: 10px;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: buttonface !important;
}
```

Any idea how to resolve this problem

Comment: in your example the second css file will overwrite the first file.  [this may help you](http://jsfiddle.net/fp9cQ/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you two CSS rules with the same selectors, the second one loaded in the second style sheet is the one that will be used.

This concept is known as the cascade, and described in the CSS specification:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade

Answer (score 1):

You can't , All CSS on page will be applied (the HTML "knows" nothing about this process), and the individual rules with the highest specificity will work. Specificity is determined by the selector and by the order they appear in the document. This is part of the cascading.